# Storing numpy sparse matrix in HDF5 (PyTables)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, hdf5, pytables

I am having trouble storing a numpy csr_matrix with PyTables. I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: objects of type ``csr_matrix`` are not supported in this context, sorry; supported objects are: NumPy array, record or scalar; homogeneous list or tuple, integer, float, complex or string
```

My code:

```
f = tables.openFile(path,'w')

atom = tables.Atom.from_dtype(self.count_vector.dtype)
ds = f.createCArray(f.root, 'count', atom, self.count_vector.shape)
ds[:] = self.count_vector
f.close()
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you worried about the size of the data on disk? I think hdf5 files can be stored in compressed format, in which case you might get away with just storing the dense matrix.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895120/using-pytables-which-is-more-efficient-scipy-sparse-or-numpy-dense-matrix, it looks like there is no pytables support for sparse matrices.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A CSR matrix can be fully reconstructed from its `data`, `indices` and `indptr` attributes. These are just regular numpy arrays, so there should be no problem storing them as 3 separate arrays in pytables, then passing them back to the constructor of `csr_matrix`. See the [scipy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html).

**Edit:** Pietro's answer has pointed out that the `shape` member should also be stored

Comment: I believe the point, though, is to use it like a dense matrix. How could I convert a csr_matrix to a "dense-format" pytables instance?

Comment: You can convert a csr_matrix to a dense array using its member function toarray, which can then be saved in pytables. Of course, this can potentially waste a lot of file space, although hdf5 has file compression options which may help.

Comment: NumPy `toarray()` can't handle converting gigantic ones to dense. I was hoping to construct the table directly from CSR.

Answer (score 35):

The answer by DaveP is *almost* right... but can cause problems for very sparse matrices: if the last column(s) or row(s) are empty, they are dropped. So to be sure that everything works, the "shape" attribute must be stored too.

This is the code I regularly use:

```
import tables as tb
from numpy import array
from scipy import sparse

def store_sparse_mat(m, name, store='store.h5'):
    msg = "This code only works for csr matrices"
    assert(m.__class__ == sparse.csr.csr_matrix), msg
    with tb.openFile(store,'a') as f:
        for par in ('data', 'indices', 'indptr', 'shape'):
            full_name = '%s_%s' % (name, par)
            try:
                n = getattr(f.root, full_name)
                n._f_remove()
            except AttributeError:
                pass

            arr = array(getattr(m, par))
            atom = tb.Atom.from_dtype(arr.dtype)
            ds = f.createCArray(f.root, full_name, atom, arr.shape)
            ds[:] = arr

def load_sparse_mat(name, store='store.h5'):
    with tb.openFile(store) as f:
        pars = []
        for par in ('data', 'indices', 'indptr', 'shape'):
            pars.append(getattr(f.root, '%s_%s' % (name, par)).read())
    m = sparse.csr_matrix(tuple(pars[:3]), shape=pars[3])
    return m
```

It is trivial to adapt it to csc matrices.

Comment: What does the `name` variable correspond to in the above answer?

Comment: @Rama: just a key to store the object. Arbitrary, you just need it to retrieve it back (in a same HDF store, you can store tons of different objects).

Answer (score 6):

I have updated [Pietro Battiston](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2858145/)'s excellent answer for Python 3.6 and [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/) 3.x, as some PyTables function names have changed in the upgrade from 2.x.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
import tables

def store_sparse_mat(M, name, filename='store.h5'):
    """
    Store a csr matrix in HDF5

    Parameters
    ----------
    M : scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
        sparse matrix to be stored

    name: str
        node prefix in HDF5 hierarchy

    filename: str
        HDF5 filename
    """
    assert(M.__class__ == sparse.csr.csr_matrix), 'M must be a csr matrix'
    with tables.open_file(filename, 'a') as f:
        for attribute in ('data', 'indices', 'indptr', 'shape'):
            full_name = f'{name}_{attribute}'

            # remove existing nodes
            try:  
                n = getattr(f.root, full_name)
                n._f_remove()
            except AttributeError:
                pass

            # add nodes
            arr = np.array(getattr(M, attribute))
            atom = tables.Atom.from_dtype(arr.dtype)
            ds = f.create_carray(f.root, full_name, atom, arr.shape)
            ds[:] = arr

def load_sparse_mat(name, filename='store.h5'):
    """
    Load a csr matrix from HDF5

    Parameters
    ----------
    name: str
        node prefix in HDF5 hierarchy

    filename: str
        HDF5 filename

    Returns
    ----------
    M : scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
        loaded sparse matrix
    """
    with tables.open_file(filename) as f:

        # get nodes
        attributes = []
        for attribute in ('data', 'indices', 'indptr', 'shape'):
            attributes.append(getattr(f.root, f'{name}_{attribute}').read())

    # construct sparse matrix
    M = sparse.csr_matrix(tuple(attributes[:3]), shape=attributes[3])
    return M
```