# What's the best way to serialize a large scipy sparse matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, hdf5, pytables

I have a large scipy sparse matrix, which is taking up >90% of my total system memory. I would like to save it to disk, as it takes hours to build the matrix...

I tried cPickle, but that leads to a major memory explosion...

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix
import cPickle

dim = 10**8

M = lil_matrix((dim, dim), dtype=np.float)

with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    cpickle.dump(M, f)  # leads to a major memory explosion, presumably there is lots of copying
```

while HDF5 didn't like the datatype: TypeError: Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent

So what should I do?

Comment: `scipy.io` has a `savemat` function that can save sparse matrices in a MATLAB compatible format.  And `loadmat` that can reload them.

Comment: See also: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.save_npz.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how much data is actually stored in the matrix. Have you looked at converting the matrix type before serialisation?

The LIL matrix is not the most memory efficient sparse matrix you have available. You could look at converting to either DIA, COO or DOK before pickling.

For example:

```
In [43]: dim = 10**6

In [44]: M = lil_matrix((dim, dim), dtype=np.float)

In [45]: for ii in range(10000):
             M[np.random.uniform(0,dim),np.random.uniform(0,dim)] = 1

In [46]: len(cPickle.dumps(M.todok()))
Out[46]: 1256302

In [47]: len(cPickle.dumps(M.tocoo()))
Out[47]: 557691

# compared to

In [48]: len(cPickle.dumps(M))
Out[48]: 23018393
```

These formats don't all support the same set of operations, but conversion between the formats is trivial.

Answer (score 5):

Pickling is very memory inefficient, unfortunately. I would recommend accessing the underlying data array attributes of the sparse matrix, and storing those in an efficient manner, such as hdf5. Reconstructing a sparse matrix from a triplet of row/column/data vectors should be easy.

Comment: so you recommend defining an M2 such that M2 = M.tocsr() and then using the solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129429/storing-numpy-sparse-matrix-in-hdf5-pytables/22589030#22589030

Comment: using either csr or coo or whatever isn't too important. The underlying data arrays of each sparse format can be accessed and stored, so it shouldn't be too hard to modify the example you linked to to any sparse format of your choosing. But yeah, that's the general idea.

Comment: This approach works well if you always need to load the entire matrix back into memory. If you need to be able to retrieve slices of the matrix (e.g. retrieving a subset of the rows) hdf5 can be slow due to [slow random access](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/293) which is required for csr and csc matrices as data in these formats aren't stored in an easily slicable way.