# Construct Sparse Matrix in Matlab from Compressed Sparse Column (CSC) format

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have a large sparse matrix (~5 billion non-zero values) in Python, stored in the [csc_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csc_matrix) format.  I need to open it as a sparse matrix in Matlab.  [savemat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html) apparently cannot save data of this size (seems to be capped at ~5GB), so I am resorting to saving it as an hdf5 file, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22589030/5877609). However, I am having trouble opening it in matlab.

Given these three vectors: `data, indices, indptr`, whose meaning is [explained](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csc_matrix):

> standard CSC representation where the row indices for column i
>   are stored in indices[indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]] and their corresponding
>   values are stored in data[indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]].

How can I construct this matrix in Matlab? I can open these three vectors in Matlab using `h5read` no problem, but I don't know how to use them to construct the sparse matrix.  This is not the format of the `sparse` command I usually use to construct a sparse matrix.

Comment: As a stop gap step I'd try the transfer using the `coo` format, data, rows, cols (adjusted for the 0/1 index start).  It won't be as compact, but it is probably more compatible.  Compared to `scipy`, `MATLAB` seems to hide a lot of the sparse format details.

Comment: @hpaulj that is a huge help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works, but is very slow. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
X=zeros(shape(1),shape(2));
for k=1:length(indptr)-1    
    i=indptr(k)+1:indptr(k+1);
    y=indices(i)+1;
    X(y,k)=data(i);
end
```